# Update contents of file via jq using redirection operator

Tags: json, cygwin, jq

My `JSON` input file is as follows:

```
{
"Name":"SA",
"Password":"yyyyy",
"Mappings" : {
"RegionMap" : {
   "us-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "xxxxxx" },
   "us-east-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "us-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "us-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ca-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-south-1"     : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-southeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-southeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-northeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-northeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "sa-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "" }       
   }
 }
}
```

My task is to update the value of the `AMI` key of `us-east-1` in the given json file and create the updated file as new file. I am using the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) plugin with redirection operator. It has [+](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) operator which can used to `overwrite` contents in an object.

My `expected` output is

```
{
"Name":"SA",
"Password":"yyyyy",
"Mappings" : {
"RegionMap" : {
   "us-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "abcd" },
   "us-east-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "us-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "us-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ca-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-south-1"     : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-southeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-southeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-northeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-northeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "sa-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "" }       
   }
 }
}
```

My current command is not providing the expected output and its as follows:

```
jq '.Mappings.RegionMap + { "us-east-1":{"AMI":"abcd"}}' 
<OldfileName> > <Newfilename>
```

Can somebody help me with achieving the expected output using redirection operator ?

I am running the command on a `cygwin` environment and my [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) version is `1.5` .

**EDIT**

Added a commas after the Password Key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue that makes your input json invalid is this line (the 3rd line):

```
...
"Password":"yyyyy"  <----
...
```

It should be followed with `,`.

After fixing that, you can easily update the needed property value:

```
jq '.Mappings.RegionMap["us-east-1"].AMI = "abcd"' oldfile > newfile
```

---

`newfile` contents:

```
{
  "Name": "SA",
  "Password": "yyyyy",
  "Mappings": {
    "RegionMap": {
      "us-east-1": {
        "AMI": "abcd"
      },
      "us-east-2": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "us-west-1": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "us-west-2": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "ca-central-1": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "eu-central-1": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "eu-west-1": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "eu-west-2": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "ap-south-1": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "ap-southeast-1": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "ap-southeast-2": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "ap-northeast-1": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "ap-northeast-2": {
        "AMI": ""
      },
      "sa-east-1": {
        "AMI": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a big deal but I would use just simple assignment `=` in this case since you're assigning a fixed value. I would reserve `|=` for cases where you need the current value to determine the new value.